# Write on MS Word or any text editor with an electronic pen

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, pen

I have pain in my fingers when typing on my ergonomic keyboard. However, I can write perfectly with a pen.

Is there any writing app. that allows to write normal text (like "Times New Roman text") with an electronic pen such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/4x3-Inches-Graphic-Drawing-8192-Pressure-Sensitivity/dp/B079BQ1BKH/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?crid=1I4IFHJ7UH52X&keywords=electronic%2Bdrawing%2Bpad&qid=1691578503&sprefix=electronic%2Bpen%2Caps%2C97&sr=8-2-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1)? So I can write and then copy-paste to Word or Confluence or whatever.

Comment: Have you checked out the Handwriting Tool built-in to Windows? It's should help you write with a pen anywhere in Windows

Comment: I use Linux and Office 365 I'm afraid.

Comment: Office 365 Online? (Which Linux distro and which browser?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chrome (or any other Chromium based) browser, you can try using the [**Google Input Tools**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab) browser extension for this.

You install the browser extension and in the options add the English Handwriting input tool:
[image]

Then you load any (or most, but I tested it on Word Online and Confluence, and it works) website and use the popup keyboard (either have it automatically pop up for new pages with text fields or open it with the assigned keyboard shortcut) and write there with the pen:
[image]